# Append id to url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
<a ui-sref="Contacts.Details.{{contact.Id}}" ng-click="showContactDetail(contact.Id)">
```

Here there  is a ui-sref in which i am giving id.
I want the url as per that contact.Id

```
state('Contacts.Details', {
    url: '/Details',
    templateUrl: 'Contact/Detail',
    controller: 'formController'
})
```

here is the config for contacts.details

i want to get contacts/details/(id which i clicked)

can any one help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the ID as a parameter in your state call:

```
<a ui-sref="Contacts.Details({contactId: contact.Id})">...</a>
```

And then recover it in your state:

```
state('Contacts.Details', {
    url: '/Details/:contactId',
    templateUrl: 'Contact/Detail',
    controller: 'formController'
});
```

[URL routing docs in `ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it

```
state('Contacts.Details', 
{
    url: '/Details:id',
    templateUrl: 'Contact/Detail',
    controller: 'formController'
})
```

Then you use

```
$state.go('Contacts.Details', {'id' : yourid});
```

to go where you want

(edit : here is how to use ui-sref)

```
ui-sref="Contacts.Details({id : yourid})"
```